# Как найти все отдельно стоящие цифры в строке? Java, Iidea IDE

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, intellij-idea

Задача найти все цифры и перечислить их через пробел.
Пример:
Дано: 12 фыва 32asd 5 dd4
Результат: 12 5

Пробую так:
`s.replaceAll("\\b\\D+\\b", "");` - не работает

Через костыли работает

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(s);

while (match.find()) {  
   String find = match.group();  
   sb.append(find + " ")
}
```

но хочется короткого и красивого решения в 1 строку :)
даже бог с ней с кириллицей.

Comment: Почему костыли? Напишите свою функцию и будет в одну строку?

Comment: Да я не против функции, просто думал что все-таки что-то делаю не так, и можно написать адекватное РегВыр для этой задачи.

Comment: Да всё так. Но понятие "адекватное решение", как я это понимаю, вовсе не означает количество знаков или строчек кода, читаемость кода играет здесь большую роль.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Stream API:

```
Arrays.stream("12 фыва 32asd 5 dd4".split("\\s"))
    .filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```