# Найти все числа в строке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Требуется написать регулярное выражение, которое ищет все числа в строке. Но если предшествующий символ - буква, то это уже не подходит. Число должно быть отдельно стоящим "словом". Я написала вот такое регулярное выржение `"[^\\w]\\d+"`, но оно не учитывает случай начала строки.

Comment: Числа какие? Отрицательные, вещественные?

Comment: Вещественные неотрицательные

Comment: Возможно дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696958/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-java-iidea-ide/696973#696973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Требуемое можно реализовать с помощью [*word boundaries*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
String source = "12 a34 5b6 78c 005 9";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[\\d]+\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
12
005
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это: `^(?:[-+0-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$`